# Getting ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

Tags: jetty, osgi, jetty-8

I'm using the class "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" in XML file to intialize it with various parameters(Please note this is an OSGi environment). However my bundle which is using the class "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" is not starting and throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:129)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:327)
```

I've made sure that the jetty server bundle is up and running and also I've made sure that I've given proper version in the "Imported-Packages" section of my manifest file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Jetty in the way that

- Jetty is initialized based on XML configuration
- It is used within an OSGi environment

I recommend that you should use [jetty-osgi-boot](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jetty-osgi-boot%22) bundle. You can find more information about its usage in the [documentation of Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-jetty-osgi.html).

In case you want to develop a custom solution based on jetty-xml, you should check how jetty-boot does it.

Some tips:

- The configuration is read from the XML file in the end of [ServerInstanceWrapper.configure()](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.9.v20150224/jetty-osgi/jetty-osgi-boot/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/osgi/boot/internal/serverfactory/ServerInstanceWrapper.java#L161) function.
- That is called from [DefaultJettyAtJettyHomeHelper.startJettyAtJettyHome(...)](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.9.v20150224/jetty-osgi/jetty-osgi-boot/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/osgi/boot/internal/serverfactory/DefaultJettyAtJettyHomeHelper.java#L161)
- There you will find the trick that the Thread Context Classloader is overridden until the Server is configured from the XML.

  ```
  ClassLoader contextCl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  try
  {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(JettyBootstrapActivator.class.getClassLoader());

      ...

      Server server = ServerInstanceWrapper.configure(null, configURLs, properties);

      ...

      return server;
  }
  ...
  finally
  {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextCl);
  }
  ```

Please note that the links and example is from Jetty 9.2.9 as the code is a bit nicer there, but you can find the same or similar logic in the jetty-osgi-boot of your Jetty version.

It is not a good thing to play around with the Thread Context ClassLoader, but sometimes it is necessary, when code is called that use TCL. The best would be if the XMLConfiguration class of Jetty accepted a ClassLoader as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, i'm using a custom solution based on jetty.xml. I tried the same approach jetty-osgi-boot is using(Changing the contextclassloader to point to activator's classloader), but it didn't work. Not sure if i"m missing something.

Comment: "Changing the contextclassloader to point to activator's classloader": I guess you changed to the classLoader of your Activator that is the classloader of your bundle. Does that classloader see the class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server? I mean, does the bundle import the org.eclipse.jetty.server package? If you check the source of org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:92), you will see that the context classloader is used. So either you made a mistake during setting the classloader or the classloader you passed does not see that class.

Comment: I got it working finally. Thanks a lot for your help. You are awesome :)